# Unable to add new validator class to AbstractJavaValidator in Xtext

Tags: java, xtext

I have a small problem here . Even though it is related to Xtext i think the solution may be more java related .

I am using Xtext to create a grammar which works fine . There was an existing validation called BufferValidator for the grammar . Its defined correctly as

```
public class BufferValidator extends AbstractSPJavaValidator {

// Validation methods which work fine 

}
```

I added another .

```
public class FreqValueValidator extends AbstractSPJavaValidator{

    // Some new validation methods

}
```

Now when i run the project the folder src-gen/ is automatically created and contains the validation information in a file called AbstractSPJavaValidator .

```
**Snip**
@ComposedChecks(validators= {gem.demo.validation.BufferValidator.class})
public class AbstractSPJavaValidator extends AbstractDeclarativeValidator {

          // Methods here 
        }

}
```

Clearly my new validator is not added to the list of `@ComposedChecks validators` . Now if i add my validator in the file myself ( which ideally i should not as this file is automatically generated ) it works as expected .

Any idea what i could be missing here . For starters i did re-create / re-generate the grammar symbols after adding the new validation class .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your situation correctly:

`BufferValidator` is the automatically generated Validator, and by default only those validations work. You want to add another Validator called `FreqValueValidator` and that only works when you manipulate the abstract class in the `src-gen` folder, which would be overwritten with the next built.

You can split your Validators and define them in the "main" Validator, `BufferValidator` in your case, with the `@ComposedChecks` annotation. In the sub validators you have to overwrite the `register` method. it not required and should not call the super method, just leave it empty with a comment.

BufferValidator:

```
@ComposedChecks(validators = { FreqValueValidator.class })
public class BufferValidator extends AbstractSPJavaValidator {

// Validation methods which work fine 

}
```

FreqValueValidator:

```
public class FreqValueValidator extends AbstractDeclarativeValidator {

    @Override
    @Inject
    public void register(EValidatorRegistrar registrar) {
        // nothing to do
    }

    // Some new validation methods
}
```

I got this solution from the official xtext support forum, but unfortunately didn't find the thread again. I'm using it and it works like a charm. I hope I got anything right in the above code, it's untested. But it should get you going.

Comment: I couldnt have hoped for a better written answer . Well formatted , concepts clearly explained . Thanks a bunch . Works like a charm .